# Im looking for a Java program for which results result should as below. i stuck in the middle

Tags: java, arrays, logic

```
input: statement
output: sta tat ate tem eme men ent
```

[basically length of the each output be based on length of the second array] here 3

This is what I tried:

```
public class Stringg {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        char[] array1 ={'a','c','t','i','a','n','c','e'};
        char[] array2 ={'a','n','c'};
        System.out.println(array1.length);
        System.out.println(array2.length);
        String Str ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length-array2.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i; j < array1.length-array2.length; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(array1[j]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output is :

```
8
3
actiactiatiaiaa
```

Comment: What would be the desired output for the second case?

Comment: Please change your title to reflect the actual issue. It's currently useless.   Then explain what is wrong with your code.

Comment: basically i trying get match substring with main string usiing above method... i.e array. sorry i didnt complete the few loops inside...just copied what i have done so far

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your for loops are incorrect. It should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array1.length - array2.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j < i + array2.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(array1[j]);
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Test:

```
act cti tia ian anc nce
```

Explanation:

The outer for loop loops from `0` to `array1.length - array2.length`, which are the starting indices for each possible combination. In the case of your example it will loop from `0` to `5`

The inner for loop starts from the outer for loop's current index, and increments `array2.length` times. We print out the character for each of these increments, giving the combinations.

After each combination (the inner loop finishes) we print out a space to separate the combinations.

If you print out the indices it will look like:

```
i = 0, j = 0, j = 1, j = 2
i = 1, j = 1, j = 2, j = 3
i = 2, j = 2, j = 3, j = 4
i = 3, j = 3, j = 4, j = 5
i = 4, j = 4, j = 5, j = 6
i = 5, j = 5, j = 6, j = 7
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a "just work" program for you:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input: ");
        String sourceString = scanner.next();
        combinate(sourceString);
    }

    public static void combinate(String sourceString) {
        String[] arr = sourceString.split("");
        System.out.print("output: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceString.length() - 2; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 2] + " ");
        }
    }

}

// Result

// input: statement
// output: sta tat ate tem eme men ent
```

Answer (score -1):

Since I am also new, and cannot ask clarifying questions, I will assume the desired output is to take increments of three characters(because of the length of the second array) from the first array. To get these values of an array you must change this statement:`for (int j = i; j < array1.length-array2.length; j++)`
to: `for (int j = i; j < i + array2.length; j++)` Also you could add a space if you like after your nested for loop

```
for (int j = i; j < array1.length-array2.length; j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(array1[j]);
        }
System.out.print(" ");
```

Comment: I can't help you solve all of it, if I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: i have solved the main problem.. but i stuck @ else part. i have to print "this isn't a sub string" only after no match found:  where to place my else here:

Comment: `code` 

 {
  char[] array1 ={'a','c','t','i','a','n','c','e'};
  String Str2 ="cti";
 
  for (int i = 0; i < array1.length-Str2.length(); i++) 
  {
   String Str ="";
   for (int j = i; j < i+ Str2.length(); j++) 
   {
    
    Str+=array1[j];
    
   }
   
   if(Str.equalsIgnoreCase(Str2))
   {
    System.out.println("This is a substring");
    break;
   }
   else{
    System.out.println("This is not a substring");
   }
      
  }
  
 }

}